# How to declare a position using the RotateAround method?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Mercury : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Mercury Sun;
    public float RotationSpeed = 100f;
    public float OrbitDegrees = 1f;
    public Sun target;

    void Awake() {
    }    

    void Start() {
        GameObject planet = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
        planet.transform.position = new Vector3(10, 10, 0);
        var planetRenderer = planet.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        planetRenderer.material.SetColor("_Color", Color.gray);
        planet.transform.localScale += new Vector3(2, 2, 2);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        transform.RotateAround(target.position, Vector3.up, OrbitDegrees);
    }
}
```

Unity keeps throwing the error:

> Assets\Galatic Items\Mercury.cs(25,39): error CS1061: 'Sun' does not
>   contain a definition for 'position' and no accessible extension method
>   'position' accepting a first argument of type 'Sun' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

It has a problem with target.position, so how do I declare Sun's position?

Comment: Aren’t you looking for target.transform.position?

Comment: Don't you think the `target` should be of type `Transform` instead of `Sun`.
And don't mind but your naming technique is a bit confusing.

Comment: Your code is harder to follow when you have type Mercury defined as sun and Sun as target...  but either way you need the transform.position of the object to rotate about

Comment: @gameDev_Unity using `Sun` as the type is actually more secure. This way you really only can reference a `Sun` here and not by accident any other object. Fully agree with the rest and other comments here, though :)

Comment: Another point: You spawn a new `Sphere` primitive, set its position and everything .... but later you only move `transform.RotateAround` the object this script is attached to but leave the spawned Sphere object on the same initial position without ever touching it again ^^ You probably wanted to make it a child of the object this script is attached to: `planet.SetParent(transform);` In general you should rather use [Prefabs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingPrefabs.html) instead of creating all your objects on runtime...